# How to get VSCode 1.14.2 to look up types in my files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

So, there's no more ///  comments and no more _reference.js and yet still I cannot figure out how to get Intellisense to show me the declaration of a type that is NOT in the currently open editor window.

Since it can do it with the open editor, it must be able to parse the JS.

How to include my js/lib/**/*.js files for Intellisense-based navigation (go to definition)?

Comment: Please remove `[vscode]` from the title. That's what the tags are for. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a [`jsconfig.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) at the root of your project:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

This file tells VS Code to treat all js files in the workspace as part of a single project

Comment: This changes nothing. I still cannot "Go to definition" of any functions not in the current file.

Comment: Please post some additional info about project structure and an small code example where go to definition does not work